# Dataflow WriteToBigQuery with STORAGE_WRITE_API doesnt accept fields starting with undescores

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-bigquery-storage-api

When deploying this step

```
WriteToBigQuery(
                    method='STORAGE_WRITE_API',
                    table=[TABLE],
                    schema=[PATH TO SCHEMA ON GCS BUCKET],
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                    insert_retry_strategy='RETRY_NEVER'
                )
```

getting

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/collections/__init__.py", line 402, in namedtuple
    raise ValueError('Field names cannot start with an underscore: '
ValueError: Field names cannot start with an underscore: '_embedded'
```

Bigquery does support fields starting with underscores.
Is this a bug and are there any workarounds?